# Can a rock in a tire tread cause a blow out?

Tags: tires, safety

A recent answer included this:

> Actually rocks in tire treads can be life threatening, if they gradually cut through the rubber and eventually cause a blow-out, and you don't usually get any warning about rocks in tire treads, unless you look for them regularly. [Source](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/60004/4694)

The last sentence about not getting any warning is false, a rock in a tire tread sounds like winter tire, but with only one stud in it.  I suppose if you have the music really loud, or no exhaust, or something there could be a scenario where you didn't hear for a long time.  But usually you know there are there, in my experience they have normally cleared themselves in a 100 miles or so.

I Googled and found a couple of pages about common flat issues and a rock in the tread is not mentioned.

- [TOP 10 MOST COMMON CAUSES OF A FLAT TIRE](https://evanstire.com/top-10-most-common-causes-of-a-flat-tire/)
- [Why Blowouts Happen—and How to Avoid Them](https://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/how-to/a9399/why-blowouts-happen-and-how-to-avoid-them-15832078/)

Could a rock stay lodged in the tread, for a really long time and cause a blowout?

Comment: Sorry, I don't buy it. I've pulled rocks out of my tires on many occasion, and in each and every case, the rock was worn flat by contact with the road (assuming, of course, that the rock in question had been there long enough).

Comment: I can't say a rock would wear though a tire, but can tell you I've had rocks lodge straight into the tread and pop a hole straight away. The rock in question was about 2" long and was triangular in shape (think obelisk with three sides). And these were good Michelin LT tires on a Suburban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant say its 100% impossible but i find it very unlikely. I say this because the centrifugal force is constantly pulling it out and the force pushing it in by the road isn't going to be straight into the tire. This will wallow out the hole its in and throw it from the tire. Takes alot to cut through the steel bands on a tire

Comment: Hmm, always find stones wedged in tires - that’s why I check mine and remove them ...

Comment: @SolarMike do you find deep cuts underneath? I have never removed stones from tires(0 off terrain driving but plenty gravel roads) and just recently got new tires. I drove those tires completely bare but there were no cracks/cuts between the treads

Comment: I notice the pointed end of the stone is always working inwards...

Comment: @SolarMike One ends facing the hard road ones facing nice and kushy rubber:)The extension cord to to pierce your tire gets shorter every revolution*. Im not saying its impossible but highly unlikely unless someone wants to provide direct proof.